# GET request from server and client

Tags: ajax, server, cors, client, cross-domain

Lets say we have other domain with API for get user by ID

```
web.com/id=5
```

My server `localhost:1337` do request on this API...

```
request.get(...web.com/id=5...)
```

And gets response with all data.

But GET ajax request from client browser with same `localhost:1337` dont work like that.

I hear about cross-origin but why my server dont care?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, APIs allow Cross Domain requests. They do this by using this header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

This header works for most cases, but there are additional headers used when dealing with custom headers, or non get/post requests.